# How can I resolve "import termcolor could not be resolved from source"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I did `pip install termcolor`, and `pip3 install termcolor`. This is what I get in CMD:

[CMD pip termcolor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq0pR.png)

When I try to use termcolor in Visual Studio Code, I'm given this error

[VSC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JtrL.png)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python, I've even tried using a completely different computer with a fresh installation of python and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command, it fixed the problem for me.

```
python3 -m pip install termcolor
```

I hope I helped!